# SAS EG how to extract, edit and insert a Program in .egp WINDOWS/Linux

Tags: linux, windows, sas

I have a scenario where .egp's are created on Windows environment. As part of migration these need to be migrated to UNIX/Linux server and from EG 4.1 to 4.2 and we have to make the programs comply with LINUX/Unix standards (like font casing) and the directory paths to the linux or unix environment.

As we have around 300 .egp's to be migrarted, Say in the first go if we use migration wizard on sas eg 4.2 version to automatically have the .egp's converted to 4.2 standards, the bigggest question is how to incorporate changes to the sas programs.Is there any automated way to extract the program from respective node in .egp, edit and insert at the same node.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the code exists purely in EG, not that I'm aware of via SAS - EG is not itself programmable.

**If** the code objects are stored as physical files outside of EG they could conceivably be imported into EG (by looping over the folders involved) and some text substitution done.

Alternatively it involves a full on scripting language. EG files are zip files, and once uncompressed contain .sas text files in subfolders within the zip file. It *should* be possible to iterate over them all and make the required changes.

In neither case will it be much fun. (Though doing it manually doesn't sound great either.)

Talk to SAS - they may have a tool they've put together for someone else they can let you have.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will followup with SAS and if i get any positive solution will post it here.

Comment: Whats wrong with combining solution #2 with #1 by extracting the files and then importing it into EG?

Comment: Kutschkem You could do that. However, I'm not sure what importing it into EG achieves. If you have access to a scripting language that could extract the text files it could probably make the change as well.